# Although undo and redo both track changes, they serve totally different purposes. What are they?

Tags: na

Although undo and redo both track changes, they serve totally different purposes. What are they? I need to know the technical definition for each action and their differences. Also I must compare these differences?

Well basically undo is undoing the action and that is the end of it. As far redo I believe that the action is still part of the memory but you are able to do the action again. If needed the prior action that was redone is still accessible.

Comment: _Undo_ and _Redo_ usually appear in text editors and similar software for example [Microsoft] Word. Are you referring to that _Undo_ and _Redo_ ? In any case, I get the impression that you are [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Is that correct? By the way, have you read [ask] ?